# Why cannot I not use connect in my React Native component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a component that I need to call dispatch in (this.props.dispatch) but dispatch doesn't exist so I decided to add a connect to my component but I get an error when I do so.  I am having trouble trying to figure out why adding a connect would throw an error when other components in my app also have a connect and don't act like this.  If I remove the connect line then the error disappears.  Does anyone know why I'm getting this error??

```
export default class ItemsInCartContent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            active: null,
            products: props.products,
            ascending: true,
            sortIcon: 'unsorted',
            sortIconStyle: styles.sortIcon
        };

        this.props.dispatch(getOrderDetails(this.props.orderId));
    }

    render() {
        const cartIcon = (<Icon name="shopping-cart"  style={styles.cartIcon} />);
        const sortIcon = (<Icon name={this.state.sortIcon}  style={this.state.sortIconStyle} />);

        return (            
            <View style={styles.itemsInCartContent}>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const {products} = state;
    return {
        products
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ItemsInCartContent);
```

[image]

Comment: I think the async request which is called in your getOrderDetails function is giving 500

Comment: You should not send actions from `constructor`.

Comment: Ok I moved my call to getOrderDetails to componentDidMount() but I still get the same error.  Even when I remove that line completely I still get that error.  Only if I remove the connect line does that error go away.

Comment: @Tanya That was not an answer, that was a comment. You can get very surprising behavior if you send actions from incorrect places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty clear if you read the log carefully:

> ... SyntaxError ... only one default export allowed per module ...

You got

```
export default class ItemsInCartContent extends Component {
```

and

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ItemsInCartContent);
```

only one of those exports can be `default`.

I would advise to remove the export on `ItemsInCartContent` completely since the component is supposed to be used with `connect`, or, make it explicit:

```
export class ItemsInCartContent extends Component {
```